# exception handling for deleting dependent objects (jpa/rest-service)

Tags: java, rest, http, jpa, entity

Which exception makes the most sense to throw, when i delete an object, which has a dependency to another object (jpa). And which status code should i return, i just saw that 424 could fit, but the wiki description doesn't support this theory:

> 424 Failed Dependency (WebDAV; RFC 4918)
>
> The request failed due to failure of a previous request (e.g., a PROPPATCH).[4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
409 - Conflict.

The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource.
```

Also you could add the message in the body explaining why the conflict exists.